# Reading config files within Web-INF in RESTLET

Tags: java, servlets, restlet, restlet-2.0

I'm trying to read a config file placed inside the root path of WEB-INF. The application is using RESTLET framework. I read in the official RESTLET [doc](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/snapshot/gae/ext/org/restlet/ext/servlet/ServerServlet.html) that its possible to read files via a WAR connector ("war:///WEB-INF/web.xml") using Context.getClientDispatcher().

However i was not able to figure out as to how this can be achieved. Kindly let me know about this or any other ways a file can be read using RESTLET

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution for this. I had to access the ServletContext to get to the configuration text file. Here is the code sample -

```
// Extract the ServletContext from the attributes of RestletContext
    ServletContext servlet = (ServletContext) context.getAttributes().get("org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServletContext");
// Get the path of the config file relative to the WAR
    String rootPath = servlet.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/configuration.txt");
    Path path = Paths.get(rootPath);
    File configFile = new File(path.toString());
    FileRepresentation file = new FileRepresentation(configFile, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
```